# C# mvc4 - direct URL to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url, redirect

I have an external URL that points directly to a function in my controller but when I click on it for the first time, instead of reaching the page, I get to the home page. However, on the second click (and the following ones), I can reach the desired page.

Is there something I should add to my function or controller to allow to have it reached on the first click? Or would it be my sessions that aren't initialized on the first time? I tried debugging, but I never reached the desired function on the first click.

Here is my external URL pointing to my controller:
http://localhost/careers/postings/index?pvnID=HC-1505-000533

and here is the method from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string pvnID)
    {

        //if pvnid matches legacy PVN application pater -> refirect to legacy application
        Regex pattern = new Regex("[A-Z]{3}-\\d{3,4}");
        Match match = pattern.Match(pvnID);
        if (match.Success)
        {
         //redirect to legacy application
        }
        else 
        {
            model.Job = jobPostingMgr.GetJobPosting(pvnID);

            string maxSalary = "";
            string minSalary = "";

            if(model.Job.MaximumSalary.ToString() != "0.00"){
                maxSalary = String.Format("{0:C}", model.Job.MaximumSalary);
            }
            if (model.Job.MinimumSalary.ToString() != "0.00")
            {
                minSalary = String.Format("{0:C}", model.Job.MinimumSalary);
            }

            if (maxSalary != "" && minSalary != "")
            {
                ViewBag.SalaryRange = minSalary + " - " + maxSalary;
            }
            else if (maxSalary == "" && minSalary != "")
            {
                ViewBag.SalaryRange = minSalary;
            }
            else if (maxSalary != "" && minSalary == "")
            {
                ViewBag.SalaryRange = maxSalary;
            }


            //data processing
            Session["category"] = model.Job.Category;
            model.Job.Category = miscInfoMgr.GetAJobCategory(model.Job.Category).Description;
            model.Job.CollegeCode = PvnHelper.GetCollege(model.Job.CollegeCode).Description;
            Session["pvnid"] = pvnID;


            //Change to lower case 
            model.Job.DisplayJobTitle = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(model.Job.DisplayJobTitle.ToLower());
            model.Job.Department = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(model.Job.Department.ToLower());
            model.Job.CollegeCode = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(model.Job.CollegeCode.ToLower());
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you got any security.

Comment: Please provide code of your controller and that url too

Comment: I added the code to the original thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have forgotten to specify name of the controller in Html.ActionLink() parameter. Try Html.ActionLink("actionname","controllername");

Comment: I don't use Html.ActrionLink(). It's a plain URL pointing to the application controller.

Comment: It might be that MVC route map does not have definition for that kind of url. If your URL would be localhost/postings/index?pvnID=asjdoia, MVC would look PostingController with Index(string pvnID). Register new route for that kind of url.

Comment: I didn't have to add a new route but found out that if the session wasn't started, the application would redirect to the root. Hence why the link wouldn't work on the first click but then would.